# Laravel Auth Login form redirect when already Login

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2. And I want to ask a question. How to change redirect login form on laravel when we already do login ? I am using auth from Php artisan make:auth. here is what I mean :

- I already login and redirect to localhost:8000/admin
- then I open again localhost:8000/login . it will redirect to "/" or localhost:8000/
- my question is how to change that "/" to "/admin" ? so even I already logged in and when I want to open localhost:8000/login, I dont want it redirect to "/" but to "/admin" or localhost:8000/admin

I think its on AuthController so here is my AuthController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    // protected $redirectPath = '/admin';
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';
    protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/login';
    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

when I search what is Route::auth() I found this :

```
$this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
$this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

// Registration Routes...
$this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

So I think the problem is on 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm'. then on AuthController I cannot found

```
public function showLoginForm {}
```

so if I want to do something with this function what must I do ?? its look like if I am already login then redirect to /admin else do login(or redirect to /login)

and here is my Route :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

//admin
Route::get('admin', function() {
    return view('admin.index');
});

//login
Route::auth();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to edit the `App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware like so :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
     if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
         return redirect('/admin');
     }

     return $next($request);
}
```

Or you may have a middleware specifically for that.

in your console `php artisan make:middleware RedirectIfAdmin` and edit the `handle` method like the above one then register that middleware in `App\Http\Kernel` like that:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
   ...
   'RedirectIfAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAdmin::class,
];
```

and attach that middleware to the controller constuctor :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('RedirectIfAdmin', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Very much !! I dont know we can do it on middleware.. I am a newbie on laravel so I dont know about it.. thanks !! you help me much !!

Comment: you are welcome, try to look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication)